# What library does Capybara use as CSS selector?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, cucumber, integration-testing, capybara

For my acceptance tests I use Steak and Capybara (+ Envjs).
When trying to find an element like this `find("#ticker").find("li:eq(0)")` it tells me `Unable to find 'li:eq(0)'`, but `find("#ticker").find("li:eq(1)")` return the correct first `li` element in the list.
I am used to that eq selector starts with 0 (jQuery). Why does eq selector in Capybara starts with 1? Bug or feature?

## Update

It seems that it is some unofficial selector which works like `nth-child`. What does Capybara (/Envjs) use under the hood for selectors? It doesn't seem to be jQuery as it would start with eq(0) as mentioned above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Capybara uses [Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/) under the hood.